# How to make a Primary Key as a Foreign Key too in Oracle APEX?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, oracle-apex, primary-key

[Here is the ERD, it is in the table 'PROCESS' I am referring to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Q0I.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Don't create inline constraints, but outline:

```
create table process
  (cust_id     number,
   prod_id     number,
   --
   constraint pk_proc      primary key (cust_id),
   constraint fk_proc_cust foreign key (cust_id) references customer (cust_id),
   constraint fk_proc_prod foreign key (prod_id) references product  (prod_id)
  );
```